# Every abelian category is exact category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

This is a statement mentioned in Rotman Homological Algebra which I did not find the proof of the statement in the book.

"Every abelian category is an exact category."

Given any short exact sequence $0\to A_1\to C\to A_2\to 0$ with $A_i$'s objects of abelian category, I can always have $0\to A_1\to A_1\oplus A_2\to A_2\to 0$. However, it is not clear how to extend the map from $C\to A_1\oplus A_2$ to argue $C$ is an object of abelian category. I do not know how to proceed with this statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every abelian category $\mathcal{P}$ is an exact category by simply considering it as a subcategory of itself.  Then trivially the object $C$ must be in $\mathcal{P}$ because $\mathcal{P}$ is the entire category.

If you in general consider an abelian category $\mathcal{P}$ which is a full subcategory of a larger abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, then $\mathcal{P}$ need not be closed under extensions.  For instance, the category of $\mathbb{Z}/2$-vector spaces is full abelian subcategory of $Ab$, but it does not contain the extension $0\to\mathbb{Z}/2\to\mathbb{Z}/4\to\mathbb{Z}/2\to 0$.